# Have a Laravel model have a relationship with 2 different models

Tags: php, laravel-5, relational-database

My setup so far is a customer contact portal, and there is an Organization, Contact and Note models. A Contact belongs to an Organization, and an Organization has many Contacts. I have no problems with that, however I am having an issue trying to tie the Notes model to be able to have a relationship with both the Organization and Contact. Basically so I can leave a Note on an Organization but also leave another note on the Contact, and be able to search for Notes that belong to a given Contact or Organization.

I first thought of a pivot table that stored the ids of the models as well as the model type. Which I think is the same as a polymorphic pivot table? However I have not played with that yet, and not sure where to start.

Is the pivot table the way to do it? Or is there an easier way so I don't have additional tables all in my database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [Polymorphic Relations.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

From the docs:

> Table Structure
>
> Polymorphic relations allow a model to belong to more than one other model on a single association. For example, imagine users of your application can "comment" both posts and videos. Using polymorphic relationships, you can use a single comments table for both of these scenarios. First, let's examine the table structure required to build this relationship:
>
> ```
> posts
>     id - integer
>     title - string
>     body - text
>
> videos
>     id - integer
>     title - string
>     url - string
>
> comments
>     id - integer
>     body - text
>     commentable_id - integer
>     commentable_type - string
> ```
>
> Two important columns to note are the commentable_id and commentable_type columns on the  comments table. The commentable_id column will contain the ID value of the post or video, while the commentable_type column will contain the class name of the owning model. The  commentable_type column is how the ORM determines which "type" of owning model to return when accessing the commentable relation.
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App;
>
> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
>
> class Comment extends Model
> {
>     /**
>      * Get all of the owning commentable models.
>      */
>     public function commentable()
>     {
>         return $this->morphTo();
>     }
> }
>
> class Post extends Model
> {
>     /**
>      * Get all of the post's comments.
>      */
>     public function comments()
>     {
>         return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
>     }
> }
>
> class Video extends Model
> {
>     /**
>      * Get all of the video's comments.
>      */
>     public function comments()
>     {
>         return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
>     }
> }
> ```

In your case, the "Comment" model corresponds with your "Note" model and the other ones (Video and Post) with your Organization and Contact models.

Give it a try.

---

In relationships, Laravel does not create the intermediate tables, you should add them using [Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations). Your Notes table should have, at least, the following fields:

- **`id`**: (or `note_id`) the key of the table.
- **`notable_id`**: Indicates the foreign key of Organization or Contact.
- **`notable_type`**: Indicates to what model the Note object is refering to. (so the previous field know in wich table should look to find the correct object).
- The rest of your Note fields like `title` or `description` ...

Comment: How would the table for the Notes get setup? Do I still need to set the `notable_id` as unsigned? Will Laravel make the pivot table, or does it not create an actual pivot table?

Comment: Excellent, that worked perfectly! Do I use the associate() or the attach() query builder command though?

Comment: @hightekjonathan haven't use polymorphic relationships a lot, but I think that doing `$contact->notes()->save($note);` should work.